# Laravel 5 Entrust - Users belong to many apps

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, authorization, entrust

I am using Entrust package in Laravel 5.3 for managing user roles and permissions, and it works perfectly.

The problem is that my **users** *belong to many* **apps**, so I need to check roles and permissions having into account in which app are they trying to perform the actions in each case.

As Entrust does not provide that feature out of the box... Should I add an **app_id** field to the pivot Entrust **role_user** table?
Then, how would I check the roles in each case? By overriding Entrust methods?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for the record, I have found a Laravel 5 Package called Laratrust (https://github.com/santigarcor/laratrust/tree/master) which in its master branch now supports "groups implementation", where roles can be attached to users within a group.
And that is exactly what I needed, considering my **apps** as **groups**, so I am going to give it a try :)

Digging a little into the code and its database design, I have to say that I was right when I thought of adding an **app_id** field to the pivot *role_user* table... That is exactly as this package implements that relation.

Thanks ;)